# how to write/print href links with link text/title - javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href, linktext

this is my code - not complete.

how to write/print href links with link text/title.
result like this
http://google.com/123.asp
123
http://google.com/456.asp
456
http://google.com/789.asp
789

```
<y id='txt'>
<a href="http://google.com/123.asp">123</a>
<a href="http://google.com/456.asp">456</a>
<a href="http://google.com/789.asp">789</a>
</y>


<script>

    var y = document.getElementById("txt");
   var linktext = p.getElementsByTagName("textcontent");
   const links = document.links;
   var text = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < linktext.length; i++){
       text += links[i] + "<br>" + linktext[i].innerHTML + "<br>";
   }
    
   p.innerHTML = text;



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

`

```
<script>    
var y = document.getElementById("txt");
var links = y.getElementsByTagName('a')
var text = '<p>';
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
   text += '<a href="' + links[i].getAttribute('href') + '">' + links[i].getAttribute('href') +  '</a>'  + " " + links[i].innerText + "<br/>";
}

text+= '</p>'

y.innerHTML = text;

</script>
```

`